# What should I do about unaccepted answers?

Tags: discussion, answers

What should I do if I feel my answer is correct and I am the only who has answered, but it is not accepted?

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think that all the answers that I post are correct ;-)

Comment: Thou art the man! (--Stanislaw Lem)

Comment: Recently I answered a question in MSE which had a +100 bounty associated. The answer was fine, and it got 2 upvotes and the OP accepted it, still without awarding me the bounty. But one day later, this guy decided to award me the bounty and unaccept my answer, at the same time! What's up what that? I should point out that mine is the first and only answer to the question. The only thought stopping me from thinking this guy is a doing this out of some weird spite, is to think that he came up with a better answer, and he will post it eventually. But then again, who knows?

Answer (score 18):

Nothing.  There is no requirement to accept any answers on the sites.

Comment: Which is a rather stupid notion as the questions don't get closed. I'm often (re) reading questions that are left open and take away my valuable time. There should be some community method about forcing an answer to get accepted, especially for drive by users.

Answer (score 9):

Can you link to the question?  If it's a new user who may or may not have come back to the site, there may be nothing you can do.  If it's a regular user you can leave a comment asking if your answer solved their problem.

I've had answers accepted over a year after I left them, so sometimes you just have to be patient.

Answer (score 3):

> What should I do if I feel my answer is correct and I am the only who has answered but it is not accepted?

Just follow all of your suggestion in sequence:

1. Wait a decent while before doing anything.
2. Comment on the question (**edit**: not on the answer!) asking the OP for either feedback on the answer if it hasn't worked out for them or acceptance if it has. @-mentioning the OP in your new comment for clarity/emphasis.
3. Make sure that your answer sounds more like a statement than a suggestion, i.e. "XYZ will do what you want" rather than "Try XYZ, it will probably help" - that is, of course, assuming you know for sure that XYZ will do what OP wants; otherwise you're not sure yourself that your answer should be accepted.

Comment: @rene: Added an initial anti-noise point. However - this is not so much about your ego as an answerer, it's about other users who can't trust the answer when it hasn't been accepted.

Comment: @einpoklum maybe we should make clear then that votes is the signal that should be trusted not the accept mark. Because votes are the judgement calls of many users, the accept mark only one. Problem solved ;)

Comment: @rene: They mean different things. An upvoted answer doesn't necessarily mean it resolved the problem.

Comment: Nor does an accepted answer. That only signals: This answer worked for the OP. Nothing withheld them from accepting a factual wrong answer.