# Unaccepted answers

Tags: discussion, answers

Often I write answers, and the person who wrote the question will comment "Thanks, that worked!" or similar, without accepting the answer. I usually feel really uncomfortable asking them to accept the answer, as I feel like it's fishing for reputation.

What's the community's thought on this? Should I comment asking for them to accept the answer?

Comment: Accepting answers is for the better of the site, not just your rep. When the OP says it worked I recommend them to mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: See this question:http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119197/problem-with-users-not-accepting-answers?lq=1

Comment: Related: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/430/text-building-blocks section **Please ‘accept’ an answer below**

Comment: @tohecz I actually don't particularly like that message.

Comment: @Bart I usually modify that one to suit the specific case. The text building blocks are important so that you don't have to start from zero every time, and you don't have to look up the corect links ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If they are a new user, the easiest and least whore-like way to do it is to drop 
a link to the meta-faq entry in a comment:

[How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

In general, though, accepting an answer is a completely optional activity.  User's shouldn't feel obligated to accept answers, beyond letting them know that the option to click the checkmark is available to them.