# Warn new users that they cannot accept more than one answer

Tags: feature-request, voting, accepted-answer, new-users

A typical error made by new users is trying to accept more than one answer to one of their questions. Therefore, I suggest that if a low reputation user (let us say, an user whose reputation is below 100) accepts an answer less than a minute after having accepted another answer to the same question, then that user should get a warning like:

> Be aware of the fact that no question can have more than one accepted answer. If you mark an answer as accepted, then any previous answer (to the same question) that you have also marked as accepted becomes un-marked. But you can upvote several answers (as long as you have enough reputation to upvote answers).

I suggest this because it is rather frustating for a user who posted an answer to see it marked as accepted and then unaccepted and the accepted again and so on several times.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26639/allow-users-to-mark-accepted-answer-on-someone-elses-question?rq=1

Comment: Remoptely related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119197/problem-with-users-not-accepting-answers and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214204/how-to-encourage-users-to-accept-answers

Answer (score 11):

> A typical error made by new users consists in trying to accept more than one answer to one of their questions.

How do you know that this is really erroneous behavior, but not choosing a better answer to be accepted by the OP?

Shouldn't they quickly realize that accepting another answer for their question unmarks the previously marked question?

I think it's not worth the developer efforts to realize such warning.
It also sounds a bit too patronizing, and may confuse new users who just made their choice.

Also I don't see much value for improvement of quality. The acceptance mark is just indicating what helped the OP best in their opinion.
For the quality of answers the real indicator are the upvotes gained from the community and future researchers.

---

Maybe some new and unexperienced users would even try to gain more than the original 2 pt reputation by accepting another answer to their question. They also should quickly realize that this doesn't work.

---

> I suggest this because it is rather frustating for a user who posted an answer to see it marked as accepted and then unaccepted and the accepted again and so on several times.

I understand that frustration, but that's not an indicator of overall quality regarding the originally chosen answer, or the OP's real intends.

I'd recommend you should develop a thicker skin regarding reputation gain or loss.

---

Even if such thing should be implemented, it would be better to raise a popup like

> > Please note that the previously accepted answer will no longer be marked as accepted now.

when accepting a different question. But not warn the OP before doing that, and give them a choice to cancel their operation.

Comment: I have seen several times new users trying desperately to mark two answers as accepted. It takes them some time to realize that they can't.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos _" It takes them some time to realize that they can't."_ Well, a few people seem to be stubborn. I am still in good faith that the majprity would realize that at the 3rd trial.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos - I can't see this being common behaviour at all, but in any case it really doesn't matter